# firebaseUser.getUid() not working

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have a recycler view wherein there is a delete option for each post. The delete option should be enabled only if the user is the owner of that particular post or else the delete option should be disabled. I am using firebase authentication to check if the user is the owner or not. The problem I am facing is that even if the user is the owner of the post, she is not able to use the delete option as it is disabled. I am not sure where the problem lie but I think it is not able to fetch the user id. Below is my code.

```
    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(savedCollname).child(node);

final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainBlogView, MainView.MainViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MainBlogView, MainView.MainViewHolder>(
                        MainBlogView.class, R.layout.recyclerplace, MainView.MainViewHolder.class, databaseReference
                ) {
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String userId=firebaseUser.getUid();
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(ctx1, viewHolder.buttonViewOption);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    final Menu pop = popup.getMenu();
    databaseReference.child(post_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          String user_id = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
          if (firebaseUser.getUid().equals(user_id)) {
          pop.findItem(R.id.delete).setEnabled(true);
        } else  {
          pop.findItem(R.id.delete).setEnabled(false);
          }
        }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
    });
```

Below is the json tree:

```
{
  "AlertPost" : {
    "-L2Zrn-UM1BD0CDh4yFN" : {
      "description" : "fhjhg",
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/notefi-86d18.appspot.com/o/Alert_Image%2Fcropped1486185224.jpg?alt=media&token=61520d4a-5f3b-458d-bf1d-98c1f337a369",
      "timestamp" : 1515668320717,
      "uid" : "qrnu8UaYAsPJjFhHryiYjnbVgu93"
    }}
```

Comment: Problem is in your code not in firebase.. look into the logic you have implemented to match uid and enablement of delete option.

Comment: But I think everthing is fine with the code!@PankajKumar